# AngularJS with Web Api, Sign In OWIN and ADFS

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, adfs3.0

**The scenario:**

I have an ADFS (On Premises) server and what i want is to authenticate an angularJS app against it. For what i was looking i must use the Authorization_Code Flow.
So, using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) and OAuth2 flow, i try to authenticate, ADFS responds with an authorization code that part is OK, when ADFS responds automaticaly redirects the code to http://localhost/token where is my web api. But i cant obtain the token because i dont know how to call obtain it from ADFS once /token is called.

My OWIN startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();


        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(config);

        var container = IoCModule.SimpleInjectorWebApiContainer();
        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
            new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                }
            });          

    }
}
```

Satellizer config:

```
$authProvider.oauth2({
    name:'ADFS',
    url:'/token',
    clientId:'devAngular',
    redirectUri:'//localhost/myapp',
    authorizationEndpoint:'https://adfs.my.domain/oauth/authorize',
    defaultUrlParams:['response_type','client_id','redirect_uri','resource_server'],
    rourceServer:'https://localhost/myapp',
    responseType: 'code',
    responseParams: {
        code: 'code',
        clientId: 'clientId',
        redirectUri: 'redirectUri'
    }
});
```

**This is only and idea for OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider:**

```
public override async Task GrantAuthorizationCode(OAuthGrantAuthorizationCodeContext context)
        {
            var message = new HttpClient();
            var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ""));
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", ""));
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", ""));
            var response = await message.PostAsync("https://adfs.my.domain/oauth/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));

            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(content); 
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims);
            var properties = CreateProperties(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
```

If someone can help with orientation on how achieve the token grant. I already have the httpInterceptor for angular and, i think that the **app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication** is the way that Web Api validates the bearer token.

Thanks!